# Dose the size of a USB flash drives storage capacity influence its transmission speed?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

Someone tell me that  a USB flash drive with smaller capacity have faster transmission speed, is that true? If so, could someone please explain the reason for that?
**P.S.** English is not my native language, so sorry for my English.

Comment: No; there is no connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not true. The transmission speed of a usb flash drive depends on usb version.
There are USB 2.0 and USB 3.0

USB 3.0 transfer speed at maximum of 640 Megabytes per second while USB 2.0 can handle up to 60

Size/capacity does not show how fast a USB is

Comment: unless you are trying to access many parts simultaneously maybe? Reading from more data could cause a perceived drop in speed, but i can't think of many cases where you would be reading from or writing to all the cells in the drive

Comment: A USB hub is all I can think of.